# Javascript preventing submit based on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why this code will not prevent a submit. All html is linked properly. All alerts display as expected.  It doesn't seem as though I am losing scope on the event. Any suggestions, fixes or explanations would be awesome!

```
//Alert the potential customer if the email entered already exists.
function emailUniqueness() {

// When the Submit Button is clicked, then execute the following function... 
 $('#form').submit(function(event) {                 

    //Remove error messages if they exist
    $("#emailNotUniqueErr").empty();
    $("#emailNotUniqueErr").removeClass('alert alert-warning');

    //Make the call to servlet method
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/ShoppingCart/ajax.do',
        success: function(response) {

            searchForEmail(response, event);
        }
    });

    //event.preventDefault(); works when placed here but is pointless.   
});
}

function searchForEmail(response, event) {
    //alert returns type "submit"
    alert(event.type);
    var emailEntry = $("#email").val();
    var emailExists = false;

    $.each(response, function(index, item) { 

        if(emailEntry == item.email) {

            //Set to true when a match is found
            emailExists = true;
            //Exit the .each loop
            return false;
        }
    });

//alert returns appropriate true or false for input entry
    alert(emailExists);
    if(emailExists) {

        //still is type submit
        alert(event.type);
        //Properly print the warning if email exists
        $("#emailNotUniqueErr").addClass('alert alert-warning col-sm-offset-2');
        $('<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>').appendTo("#emailNotUniqueErr");
        $('<strong>Warning! Account already exists. One account per Email.</strong>').appendTo("#emailNotUniqueErr");

        //does not prevent submit???
        event.preventDefault();


    } else {
        //No match found allow submit, remove errors
        $("#emailNotUniqueErr").empty();
        $("#emailNotUniqueErr").removeClass('alert alert-warning');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to run the searchForEmail() function first and then decide whether or not to use AJAX? It seems like you are just submitting via AJAX and no matter what happens, it will always submit since you are only calling the function after the AJAX request has gone through. I could be wrong though.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent a submit"? You want to prevent default submit behavior (POST or GET to another url), or you want to prevent the ajax calls?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the default submit behavior(form POST) when an email match occurs.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I need AJAX to get the data then `searchForEmail()` decides whether a submit(POST) should be allowed or not.  I'm not sure the proper way to structure this to have the event prevented within `emailUniqueness()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajax` call is asynchronous. Therefore the line `searchForEmail(response, event);` is executed with some delay (when the response comes for the request). When it is executed the form is already submitted. The order of execution is given below.

1. Function `emailUniqueness()` is called and execution of the function starts
2. `ajax` request is sent scheduling the callback to be executed after the response comes
3. Function `emailUniqueness()` function execution ends
4. Form submission
5. Response for the `ajax` request comes, callback executed, `searchForEmail(response, event);` is called
6. `event.preventDefault()` is called (this is called  after the form is submitted)

You have to call the method `event.preventDefault();` inside `emailUniqueness()` function which changes the order to the following.

1. Function `emailUniqueness()` is called and execution of the function starts
2. `ajax` request is sent scheduling the callback to be executed after the response comes
3. `event.preventDefault()` is called (this prevents form submission)
4. Function `emailUniqueness()` function execution ends
5. Response for the `ajax` request comes, callback executed, `searchForEmail(response, event)` is called

---

As a solution,

1. prevent the form submission inside `emailUniqueness` function
2. submit the form with `$('#form').submit()` inside `searchForEmail` function.

Comment: I agree, I know it works within `emailUniqueness()` just having a difficult time figuring how to trigger `event.preventDefault()` with the the logic from `searchForEmail()` inside `emailUniqueness()`.

Comment: You cannot use only `event.preventDefault` here. Instead prevent the form submission with `event.preventDefault` inside `emailUniqueness` function and submit the form with `$('#form').submit()` inside `searchForEmail` function..

Comment: Great answer, thanks for breaking it down for me!! Makes perfect sense now.